# ¿ Cómo ejecutar una url con javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

Tego una página html que ejecuta un script que deberia abrir una url un archivo php y cargar un div con los datos de la base de datos pero al intentar abrir la página no funcióna por que tengo un error en el bucle de javascript que deberia resolver la url el error dice Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length'), no comprendo muy bien javascript no se que estoy haciendo mal dejo mi codigo a continuación

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="css/check.css" rel="stylesheet">


        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/check.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/modal.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.orgchart.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tabs.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/easy-autocomplete.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/easy-autocomplete.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/easy-autocomplete.themes.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/easy-autocomplete.themes.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/diagrama.css" media="screen">


        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easy-autocomplete.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mockjax.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.orgchart.js?v2.0"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/configuraciones.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.easy-autocomplete.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.table2excel.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vistacolaborador.js?v2.0"></script>
        <script src="js/logregister.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

       
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container-fluid text-center">


      </div>
        <div class="">
            <table id = "resumen" class="tableRes" style="display:none"></table>
        </div>


        <div id="chart-container2" class="divDiagrama" style="overflow-x:scroll;display:none" >
            <center>
                <img src="img/loading-animation.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="100" height="100" style="margin-top: 25%;">
            </center>
        </div>

        <div id="chart-container" class="divDiagrama" style="overflow-x:scroll; ">
            <span style="">
                <i class="fa fa-sitemap" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top: 25%;font-size:210px;color:#0000001f;"></i>
                <br>
                <span style="font-size: 25px;color: #bbb8b8;">Elija una categoria</span>
            </span> 
        </div>


    </body>

</html>
```

Este es el script que deberia resolver lo de la url

```
 <script>
            function CargaDiagrama(url) {

                parseFloat(url);
                $("#chart-container").hide();
                $("#chart-container2").show();
                $("ul").css("border-right", "0px");
                $("li").css("border-right", "0px");

                $(this).css("color", "#bbb");
                $(this).children().css("border-right", "4px solid");
                $(this).children().css("background", "#2c5c9e");
                $(this).css("border-right", "4px solid");
                $(this).css("background", "#2c5c9e");
                $(this).children("li").css("background", "#2c5c9e");

                var json = $(this).data("json");

                $("#chart-container").empty();
                var contador1 = 0;
                $(function () {
                    var contenido;

                    $.ajax({

                        url: url,
                        success: function (result) {
                            $("#resumen").html("");
                            var sum = 0;

                            console.log(url)

                            for (var i = 0; i < result.estructura.length; i++) {

                                sum = sum + parseInt(result.estructura[i].cantidad);
                                var html = '<tr class= "tr"><td align="left" style="text-align: left;" ><span>' + result.estructura[i].cargo + '</span></td><td align="right"><span>' + result.estructura[i].cantidad + '</span></td></tr>';
                                $("#resumen").append(html);
                            }

                            var htmlsum = '<tr class= "tr"><td align="left" style="text-align: left;" ><span><strong>Total</strong></span></td><td align="right"><span>' + sum + '</span></td></tr>';
                            $("#resumen").append(htmlsum);
                            $("#resumen").fadeIn();
                            contenido = result;
                        }

                    });
                });
            }
            CargaDiagrama("inc/funciones.php?funcion=selectRaiz");

        </script>
```

al abrir la consola en la página  se muestra el error del script

[image: error en la consola]

Comment: Lo que te dice es que `estructura` es null. Es decir, que no tiene nada. No sé qué te ha devuelto la llamada, pero eso desde luego no. Dentro de la función del success pon antes de nada `console.log(result)` y vemos qué te trae.

Comment: la variable result trae esto [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error al convertir el tipo de datos varchar a float.

Comment: y la variable url si está trayendo el link inc/funciones.php?funcion=selectRaiz

Comment: *Error al convertir el tipo de datos varchar a float* -> Arregla este error. Te recomiendo que nunca asumas que un objeto va a existir y tener lo que tu crees que debería tener. Valida siempre que algo existe y si no, imprímelo. Así siempre podrás ver qué está pasando.